# json output with native languages?

Tags: php, mysql, json

i am using json output for my application and stored all data in my native language in `mysql` server with `utf8_general_ci`

when i am fetching that using json_encode i got the json array but the data format is not supported in that. how can i solve it.

code which i used to create json data.

```
<?php 
 header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8; pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"');
    include('include/config.php');

    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf-8' 'ISO-8859-1'");


    //mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8 ISO-8859-1");

    $sth = mysql_query("select v.verse,b.book_name,v.chapter,v.verse_number from tbl_verses_mal v  inner join tbl_books_mal b on v.book_id=b.book_id");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);

?>
```

the output i got is like

```
[{"verse":"???????? ?????? ???????? ?????? ??? ????????? . ?? ????????? ??? ??????? ????????????????? .","book_name":"Genesis","chapter":"1","verse_number":"1"},{"verse":"???? ??????? ?????????? ??????? : ???????????? ???? ????????????? .????????????? ??????? ??????","book_name":"Genesis","chapter":"1","verse_number":"2"},{"verse":"???????? ?????????? ????? ???? ?????????: ???????? ??????? ","book_name":"Genesis","chapter":"1","verse_number":"3"}]
```

`?????` marks represents the language which is in the database. 
the expected results is like given below

```
[{"verse":"അയൽകാരന്  ആവശ്യം വരുമ്പോൾ നിങ്ങൾ  കടം കൊടുക്കു. .","book_name":"Genesis","chapter":"1","verse_number":"1"},{"verse":"ഭൂമി  പാഴായും ശൂന്യമായും  ഇരുന്നു : ആഴത്തിന്മീതെ","book_name":"Genesis","chapter":"1","verse_number":"2"},]
```

how can i solve this issue??

Comment: whats the encoding in your browser?

Comment: use utf-8 throughout. don't mishmash utf8 and iso-8859 together.

Comment: i used utf-8 throughout. but no change

Comment: Do you have the mbstring (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) module loaded in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf-8' 'ISO-8859-1'");
```

This makes no sense. Set the charset properly:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

Comment: when set the charset mysql_set_charset('utf8');out put like   [{"verse":"\u0d05\u0d2f\u0d7d\u0d15\u0d3e\u0d30\u0d28\u0d4d \u0d06\u0d35\u0d36\u0d4d\u0d2f\u0d02 \u0d35\u0d30\u0d41\u0d2e\u0d4d\u0d2a\u0d4b\u0d7e \u0d28\u0d3f\u0d19\u0d4d\u0d19\u0d7e \u0d15\u0d1f\u0d02 \u0d15\u0d4a\u0d1f\u0d41\u0d15\u0d4d\u0d15\u0d41\u0d15 . \u0d28\u0d40 \u0d35\u0d3e\u0d19\u0d4d\u0d19\u0d3f\u0d2f\u0d3e\u0d7d \u0d15\u0d1f\u0d02 \u0d38\u0d2e\u0d2f\u0d24\u0d4d\u0d24\u0d4d \u0d24\u0d3f\u0d30\u0d3f\u0d1a\u0d4d\u0d1a\u0d41\u0d15\u0d4a\u0d1f\u0d41\u0d15\u0d4d\u0d15\u0d41\u0d15 .","book_name":"Genesis","chapter":"1"}]

Comment: And that's exactly what you want, it's JSON encoded Unicode characters.

Comment: i want the array in [{"verse":"അയൽകാരന്  ആവശ്യം വരുമ്പോൾ നിങ്ങൾ  കടം കൊടുക്കു. .","book_name":"Genesis","chapter":"1","verse_number":"1"},{"verse":"ഭൂമി  പാഴായും ശൂന്യമായും  ഇരുന്നു : ആഴത്തിന്മീതെ","book_name":"Genesis","chapter":"1","verse_number":"2"},] format. can i make it in this format

Comment: That's the expected output. If you want to see the correct format you must use `$json['verse']`.

Comment: @bini If you use PHP 5.4+ there's a flag you can set to use raw UTF-8; otherwise it's irrelevant what you want, this is how Unicode characters are encoded in normal JSON.

Comment: IMO: that's be harder to transfer and defeat the purpose of serialization.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set character set properly try like

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

And [**`mysql_*` function are deprecated**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/2515551) use `PDO` or `Mysqli` instead